# How to append big.Int numbers to a [ ]big.Int slice?

Tags: go

I want to append `big.Int` numbers to a slice of `big.Int` type. I tried the following:

```golang
a := big.NewInt(10)
b := big.NewInt(20)

arr := new([]big.Int)
arr = append(arr, a, b)
```

However it returned with the error `first argument to append must be slice; have *[]big.Int`.
So how do I append to a `big.Int` slice?

Comment: Why are you using `new` instead of `make` to create a slice?

Comment: @Inian I am absolutely new to golang and picked it up as suggested by some SO answer.

Comment: Take tour.golang.org to learn the language. Your question is unrelated to big.Int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two options here. `big.NewInt()` returns reference to a `big.Int` value. So If you need to keep values only in the array you can use following.

```
    a := big.NewInt(10)
    b := big.NewInt(20)

    var arr []big.Int
    arr = append(arr, *a, *b)
```

If you need to store reference of the values in the array, You can use following.

```
    var arr []*big.Int
    arr = append(arr, a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly using the method to allocate memory to slice. Using `new` to get a pointer and calling it with `make` just complicates things. You could just initialise an empty slice and use `append`

And moreover `NewInt` returns a [pointer](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#NewInt) containing the value, dereference it before storing in the slice.

```golang
var arr []big.Int
arr = append(arr, *a, *b)
```

or use `make` to allocate an array and return a slice that refers to that array and store the values by indices

```
arr := make([]big.Int, 2)
```

See [Effective Go - Allocation with `make`](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#allocation_make)